# AutoNumber Creates New ID Before Record Has Been Added

Tags: database, forms, ms-access

I am trying to create a form which lets a user enter the following information for a new movie:

- Movie (name)
- Age rating
- Director ID
- (director) Forename
- (director) Surname

*Movie*, *Age Rating* and *Director ID* are fields taken from a table named 'Movies' (*Director ID* is a foreign key), whereas *Forename* and *Surname* are from a table named 'Directors' (whose primary key is *Director ID*).

Suppose that a user wants to add a new movie to the database via this form: they enter the *Movie*, *Age Rating*, and open the *Director ID* combo box:

[image]

After scanning through the list of directors, the user (erroneously) does not spot the director's name, and so proceeds to enter their *Forename* and *Surname* in the two boxes below *Director ID*, which in turn, automatically creates a new *Director ID* (presumably because *Director ID* is an AutoNumber):

[image]

The user then presses the 'add new record' button, which throws the following error:

> The changes you requested to the table were not successful because they would create duplicate values in the index, primary key, or relationship. Change the data in the field or fields that contain duplicate data, remove the index, or redefine the index to permit duplicate entries and try again.

This error occurs, because I have created an index for *Forename* and *Surname* which only allows a new record to be entered if the combination of data in these fields is unique (i.e. if a previous record has the same *Forename* and *Surname* as the new record then Access does not allow the new record to be entered).

Now that the user realises the *Director* information they are trying to enter already exists, they go back into the combo box, find the correct *Director ID* and select it:

[image]

But this yields the following error:

> The current field must match the join key '?' in the table that serves the the 'one' side of one-to-many relationship. Enter a record in the 'one' side table with the desired key value, and then make the entry with the desired join key in the 'many-only' table.

I suppose that this error occurs because the new *Director ID* was already created (see the second picture) when the *Forename* and *Surname* were erroneously entered.

What can I do to tackle this error so that the new *Director ID* is not officially created until the record is actually saved/added?

Comment: Don't use bound forms and then write a LOT of code to manage reading and writing data. Users should not even be aware of autonumber keys so gaps in sequence should be irrelevant. Hide the key fields. If you are creating a movie/director association record and selecting director, then this error should not occur. What field is combobox bound to? Make sure it is foreign key field.

Comment: Oh, wait, I guess the error could occur but other comments still apply.

Comment: New movie form only bount to "movies" table. If user can't find a `director` use combobox `not in list` function to add the new director. Director dropdown keep one column so users can take advantage of search inbuilt `predict` function. Keep it simple.